# Libgdx, Intersector.overlaps is not checking when out of focus

Tags: android, libgdx, collision-detection

I am developing a block game. i have two moving blocks in vertical direction. one of the block is also moving horizontally (like auto moving car in ROAD FIGHTER). i am checking the block interaction by  Intersector.overlaps but when my block goes out of window (i.e. position becomes less than 0) ,my code of overlaps not working .

```
if(Intersector.overlaps(block1.getBoundingRectangle(), block2.getBoundingRectangle())){ 
      // do not update values
}else{
      // update the values of block1 and block 2
}


    public static int[] value={138,195,248,303};    
public static boolean[] valueHolder={true,false,false,true};

public void update(float delta) {       
    velocity.set(0, backgroun.velocity.y-scrollSpeed);
    position.add(velocity.cpy().scl(delta));

    if(position.y>850){
        isScrollableTop=true;
    }


    selfMove(delta);
            if(position.y<-150){
                position.y=-150;            
            }

    carBoundingRectangle.setX(position.x);
    carBoundingRectangle.setY(position.y);

}

private void changeArray() {

    if(position.x>=138 && position.x<167){
        if(!GameConstants.valueHolder[0]){
            GameConstants.valueHolder[blockNumber]=false;
            GameConstants.valueHolder[0]=true;
            blockNumber=0;
        }
    }else if(position.x>=167 && position.x<222 ){

        if(!GameConstants.valueHolder[1]){
            GameConstants.valueHolder[blockNumber]=false;
            GameConstants.valueHolder[1]=true;
            blockNumber=1;
        }
    }else if(position.x>=222 && position.x<275){

        if(!GameConstants.valueHolder[2]){
            GameConstants.valueHolder[blockNumber]=false;
            GameConstants.valueHolder[2]=true;
            blockNumber=2;
        }
    }else if(position.x>=275 ){
        if(!GameConstants.valueHolder[3]){
            GameConstants.valueHolder[blockNumber]=false;
            GameConstants.valueHolder[3]=true;
            blockNumber=3;
        }
    }       
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: We need some code to tell you where the problem is. The intersector it self just checks, if the bounds you give it overlap. So it seams you are giving it wrong bounds, if they are out of your viewport.

Comment: this code is working when blocks are visible on screen but when ever block position goes less than 0 even if it is overlapping my code doesn't work .

Comment: Give some more code. Give the code of Block class.

Comment: My problem is that on regenration of blocks after going out of view cause the blocks to overlap. and cause is when i am trying to check the Intersector.overlaps when my blocks are not in view then my code of "Intersector.overlaps " is not working.

Comment: for selfMove() i am just updating x values

Comment: What is the `block1` and what does its `getBoundingRectangle` return?

Comment: block1 and block2 are two rectangles and getBoundingRect() returns the rectangle of that block. so when we can pass rectangles in Intersector.overlaps .

well for now i did implement a logic . i think that is working fine.
Thanks